# How to filter a timestamp format using Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to ask how can i filter a timestamp value in Mysql?

Let's say we have the following datetime as

**1351128031**

**1351128045**

**1351128097**

How can I create a date range using this format?
How can I perform this in a query?

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE acct_created BETWEEN (datefrom) AND (dateto) -- my problem is I can't filter the timestamp
```

Comment: Can you specify the date format

Comment: Those time stamps are since the epoch 1st Jan midnight 1970. i.e. number of seconds since then. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for the late response. For example if i want to filter the records every month using the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. But if i used the BETWEEN ('2013-01-01 00:00:00') AND ('2013-01-31 23:59:59'), i dont get any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a mysql function called  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE acct_created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('datefrom') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('dateto')
```

where datefrom and dateto are dates formated as string similar to '2012-01-01 00:00:00' in UTC

Comment: This isn't working for me... what format is the field? I'm using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/73335/6)**

**Below is the MySQL Select Query :**

```
select *,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamps`) 
  from Table1
 where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamps`) between 1351128040 and 1351128099
```